# How can I make the div tag link back to the home page?

Tags: html, navigation, hyperlink

http://www.winteradagency.com/Arvin/advantages/advantages.htm

I need the logo in the top left corner to link back to the home page for this site.  I can't figure out how to make a  tag have an anchor tag in it.

thanks!

Comment: And you want to use CSS Selectors? I would use plain old HTML: links are content, not format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an element like this in the header div to put a transparent link on top of the logo:

```
<a href="/" id="logo">&nbsp;</a>
```

Add this to the style sheet:

```
#logo { position: absolute; left: 31px; top: 26px; width: 190px; height: 190px; }
```

Comment: I had just written something like this a couple of minutes ago and it works perfectly in Firefox and IE.

Comment: This was the perfect fix.  I used a transparent gif instead of the &nbsp; because it left a small dash I couldn't get rid of.

thanks for the help!
~Andrea
http://www.winteradagency.com/Arvin/incentives/lenders.htm

Comment: @unknown: I see, the space got underlined as it was a link... Make sure to apply border:0; to the transparent gif so that it doesn't get a border because it's inside a link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a logo in the top left corner; there's the red block all across the top of the page, and then "Incentives" starts in the middle and the other choices go from the right there.  It's unclear what you want to go back to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this is a real question, given the simplicity of its answer. I can only assume I must've missed something obvious. But to address:

> > I need the logo in the top left corner to link back to the home page for this site.

There's this:

```
<div id="whatever_id">
<a href="path/to/page.html" title="path to page"><img src="path/to/image.png" alt="this is a link to whatever page." /></a>
</div>
```

To address:

> > I can't figure out how to make a tag have an anchor tag in it.

You can't, so far as I know, nest `<a>` tags. I could be wrong, but I'm sure that I read, on [Eric Meyer's site](http://meyerweb.com/) (and no, I can't find the article, sorry) that it wasn't possible. It could be effected with JS, perhaps?

Comment: Sadly the image for the logo isn't a separate image: the background image includes the logo.

Comment: It took me a while to realise what the question *was*, so my answer isn't useful. I'll delete later -I feel bad when people take the time to comment and then their comment disappears, along with the answer, into the aether...

Answer (score 0):

Since your entire header is one image (including the logo) you would need to use an image map to do it. I know Dreamweaver has an easy way to create those. Bing returns [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml) for the first link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [map tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp)  that covers the area where the logo is.

Example: note that the co-ordinates need to be the actual coordinates for the area you want to be able to click.

```
<map name="logomap">
  <area shape="poly" coords="x1,y1,x2,y2,..." href="/" alt="Home" />
</map>
```

Comment: Ah, a possibility that never even occurred to me. Clearly that's why you have 72.9K rep more than me... =]

Comment: I created a blank.gif and put it in the space above the logo and created an image map as you suggested but it screwed up everything.  So what I did was put an anchor tag in the way the 1st person suggested but now the right, top navigation disappears.
http://www.winteradagency.com/Arvin/incentives/lenders.htm

Comment: Maybe you need to play with the positioning of the image so that you get it where you want it.  Maybe wrap it in an absolutely positioned DIV so that is removed from the normal document flow.  We use a similar technique to this at http://diy.its.uiowa.edu -- you'll only be able to see the public pages, though, as it requires login.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` is just a block tag.

The tags in HTML are divided in block tags and inline tags

`<a style="display:block">` will act just like div. You replace  tag by  tag performing small changes in your css: adding {display:block} and maybe {text-decoration:none; color:black; cursor:normal}